# Image not loading in browser?

Tags: html

I am trying to show an image in a table but the image is not loading, when I try to access it from the browser it works just fine. Here is the code:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Action</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td style="float: left">Broiled Steak Kebabs With Orange Slush</td>
      <td><img src="/var/www/html/Project-Intelligent/uploads/Broiled Steak Kabobs With Orange Relish.jpg" height="50px" width="50px"></td>
      <td>BarBeCue</td>
      <td><a href="viewreceipe.php?action=delete&id=1" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>&nbsp;<a href="viewreceipe.php?action=edit&id=1" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>

 </table>
```

I have tried to change permissions to `777` but even doing this does not help.

Comment: Are you sure your web server's public directory is the root of the OS? Have you tried a relative path to the image?

Comment: Don't name images with spaces in the title. Try putting `%20` in place of each space. Also - don't use absolute paths like this - big no-no.

Comment: @staypuftman doing some experiments, of-course I am better than this

Comment: @thordarson it works with relative path but what is wrong with the given path?

Comment: Practice how you play.

Comment: @Anonymous What's your web server's root directory? Client side HTML code can't see outside of that directory.

Comment: @staypuftman Absolute paths aren't bad. They're just being used incorrectly here. Also, tables are great for, well, tables. That's what they're for. This isn't a layout, this is a table. Now that float on the other hand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute paths on web servers are relative to the directory being served by the server. If that directory is, say, /var/www/html, all absolute paths in client facing code should be relative to that.

Example:
To display /var/www/html/images/image.png on a server serving out of the directory /var/www/html using an absolute path:

```
<img src="/images/image.png">
```

Or using a relative path, given the HTML file is in /var/www/html:

```
<img src="images/image.png"> or <img src="./images/image.png">
```

Comment: What I was trying to do, was to access the images dynamically, so I decided to save absolute path to images in the database. Thanks for the answer it really helped me. Now I am accessing using a relative path as suggested by you.

Answer (score 0):

The img src is relative to the html file.

Based on the folder structure, I'm guessing your page is in the html folder, so the IMG src should be "Project-Intelligent/uploads/Broiled Steak Kabobs With Orange Relish.jpg"